# I tried it turn it on and it came on and beeped 3 times and turned off the light was green and turned to yellow

Tags: ps3

Ps3 is turning off and beeping 3 times win I try to turn it on, and the light is green and turns to yellow why?

Answer (score 1):

The Yellow Light of Death is used by the PS3 to indicate a hardware failure with the console's motherboard or power supply. Unfortunately, without repair, this PS3 won't turn on again, and repairing a PS3 is so time-consuming that it's not worth it; purchasing a new one is far easier (and probably cheaper).